# Wordpress on Ubuntu 12.10: permalinks problem

Tags: permalinks, apache, backup

I am running a backup of my website on Ubuntu 12.10 (apache+mysql).  I can see properly admin and home page, but permalinks are not working (so urls like this are failing: localhost/page/.../).

What I did till now is:

1) Created file .htaccess via settings->permalinks with the content:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

2) Added rewrite apache module with:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

3) Changed in the file sites-enabled/000-default the row:

```
AllowOverride None
```

to:

```
AllowOverride All
```

4) Finally restarted apache with:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Anyway I am still getting "not found" when I visit a permalink.

How can I make the permalinks work?

Answer (score 2):

Check in a phpinfo() that the mod_rewrite works. Also refresh the permalinks in the backend. Permalinks works fine, also on Ubuntu 12.10.

Answer (score 2):

If you have already run sudo a2enmod rewrite command but your URL Rewrite is not working.
To make .htaccess files work as expected, you need to edit this file:

**Step1** : `sudo vi /etc/apache2/sites-available/default`

**Step2** : Look for a section that looks like this:

```
    <Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
                # <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
            # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
            # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
            #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
    </Directory>

                # Uncomment this directive is you want to see apache2's
                # default start page (in /apache2-default) when you go to /
                #RedirectMatch ^/$ /apache2-default/
        </Directory>
```

You need to modify the line containing AllowOverride None to read AllowOverride All.

**step3** : sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload